# sql group by ignoring case and suffix or final letter

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table like this:

[image]

I am going to count the number of categories and how many rows are in each category.
I used this query:

[image]

But unfortunately apples is counted as separate category because it has "s" at the end.

[image]

Comment: Yeah?  That is how SQL works.  What do you want to happen?  Plurals are rather convoluted in English, so merely removing an `s` at the end doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Everything works as it should in your query. You should think of changing the reason why there ist an _apples_ in your database

Comment: Instead of storing your values like that probably you should have used a "Fruits" table where a fruit has a name and an Id. You would then simply group on Id to get the correct values for your case.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to consider apples, Apples, Apple, apple as one category not two as shown in the picture above.

Comment: On a sidenote: The `DISTINCT` in your query is superfluous, because you `group by lower(fruit)` so there is one result row per `lower(fruit)` and you select the `lower(fruit)`, too, so there can be no duplicate rows that need be removed. When aggregating it is very, very rare that we need an additional `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Saba,I presume this is homework, but what if some user added `appel`, would you also want to count that as `apple`?

Comment: @Saba: As has been mentioned: why are there even different words for the same thing in your table? If this is the case and you want to group them, then you need some dictionary table telling the DBMS that 'apple' and 'apples' is the same thing (and 'strawberry' and 'strawberries', too, for that matter).

Comment: I agree with Cetin and Thorsten: you should normalize your data model, then this query gets really easy

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at some of the comments and restructure your data as I think it will cause you issues going forward but this query will do what you want but it isnt a nice one.

CTE for testing:

```
WITH fruit_table(Fruit, No_Fruit)
AS (
SELECT 'Apple', 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Apples', 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Orange', 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'oranges', 2)
```

Query:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        LOWER(CASE
                  WHEN right(fruit, 1) = 's'
                  THEN left(fruit, -1)
                  ELSE fruit
              END),
        SUM(No_Fruit)
 FROM fruit_table
 GROUP BY LOWER(CASE
                    WHEN right(fruit, 1) = 's'
                    THEN left(fruit, -1)
                    ELSE Fruit
                END);
```

There will be a more elegant way to get the results you want and a better solution would be to fix your schema but.... it works

Comment: There is no `charindex()` in Postgres (or SQL)

Comment: i could have sworn i saw a SQL SERVER tag... the logic will be the same just use `position` or `strpos` instead

Comment: Does what is asked for, but as noted above, `strawberry` and `strawberries` isn't fixed by what was asked for...